# Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this issue with the arrayformula and importing with query function, the purpose of this is to use 2 search boxes with different criteria and extract the info. from a different sheet.

This formula stopped working for me :(

> Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 1. Actual: 25849.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(Links!C2,"Supply!A2:L"),

 IMPORTRANGE(Links!C2,"Supply!A2:B")&
 IMPORTRANGE(Links!C2,"Supply!C2:D")&
 IMPORTRANGE(Links!C2,"Supply!D2:E")},

 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col6,Col7,Col11,Col10,Col9,Col8,Col12
  where lower(Col13) contains '"&LOWER(B1)&"'", 0))
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: The problem is most likely with one of the `importrange()` calls failing. To avoid the issue, import the data to a helper sheet and point `query()` to the helper sheet instead of embedding the imports in the formula.

Comment: @Anderson Would you kindly display the desired outcome?

Comment: Your error in general is just a mismatching number of rows being returned, however we are not able to replicate since we can't see the source data. If possible can you please also share access to the spreadsheet where the data is being pulled from. Remove sensitive data if any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1 -** Try this to import all the sheet lets call it "osm" by pasting the formula in a seprate sheet and drag it to the right to get all the data, and baypass the Result too large error.

```
=IMPORTRANGE(Links!$C$2,"Supply!"&Substitute(Address(1,COLUMN(A1),4),"1","")&"2:"&Substitute(Address(1,COLUMN(A1),4),"1","")&"")
```

For all the cells in row 1

| Column | Formula |
| --- | --- |
| A | `=IMPORTRANGE(Links!$C$2,"Supply!"&Substitute(Address(1,COLUMN(A1),4),"1","")&"2:"&Substitute(Address(1,COLUMN(A1),4),"1","")&"")` |
| B | `=IMPORTRANGE(Links!$C$2,"Supply!"&Substitute(Address(1,COLUMN(B1),4),"1","")&"2:"&Substitute(Address(1,COLUMN(B1),4),"1","")&"")` |
| C | `=IMPORTRANGE(Links!$C$2,"Supply!"&Substitute(Address(1,COLUMN(C1),4),"1","")&"2:"&Substitute(Address(1,COLUMN(C1),4),"1","")&"")` |
| D | `=IMPORTRANGE(Links!$C$2,"Supply!"&Substitute(Address(1,COLUMN(D1),4),"1","")&"2:"&Substitute(Address(1,COLUMN(D1),4),"1","")&"")` |
| E | `=IMPORTRANGE(Links!$C$2,"Supply!"&Substitute(Address(1,COLUMN(E1),4),"1","")&"2:"&Substitute(Address(1,COLUMN(E1),4),"1","")&"")` |
| F | `=IMPORTRANGE(Links!$C$2,"Supply!"&Substitute(Address(1,COLUMN(F1),4),"1","")&"2:"&Substitute(Address(1,COLUMN(F1),4),"1","")&"")` |
| G | `=IMPORTRANGE(Links!$C$2,"Supply!"&Substitute(Address(1,COLUMN(G1),4),"1","")&"2:"&Substitute(Address(1,COLUMN(G1),4),"1","")&"")` |
| H | `=IMPORTRANGE(Links!$C$2,"Supply!"&Substitute(Address(1,COLUMN(H1),4),"1","")&"2:"&Substitute(Address(1,COLUMN(H1),4),"1","")&"")` |
| I | `=IMPORTRANGE(Links!$C$2,"Supply!"&Substitute(Address(1,COLUMN(I1),4),"1","")&"2:"&Substitute(Address(1,COLUMN(I1),4),"1","")&"")` |
| J | `=IMPORTRANGE(Links!$C$2,"Supply!"&Substitute(Address(1,COLUMN(J1),4),"1","")&"2:"&Substitute(Address(1,COLUMN(J1),4),"1","")&"")` |
| K | `=IMPORTRANGE(Links!$C$2,"Supply!"&Substitute(Address(1,COLUMN(K1),4),"1","")&"2:"&Substitute(Address(1,COLUMN(K1),4),"1","")&"")` |

**2 -** Then paste this in place of your formula

```
=ArrayFormula(
 LAMBDA(i, 
 QUERY({i,i&i&i},
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col6,Col7,Col11,Col10,Col9,Col8,Col12
  where lower(Col13) contains '"&LOWER(Permisos_supply!B4)&"' AND lower(Col2) CONTAINS '"&LOWER(Permisos_supply!B3)&"'", 0))({osm!A:K}))
```

**Explanation**

The first formula is the same as this:

```
=IMPORTRANGE(Links!$C$2,"Supply!A2:A)
```

to import one column `A2:A`.

We replaced 'A' with `"&Substitute(Address(1,COLUMN(A1),4),"1","")&"` to get the column letter **Dynamically** when dragged to the right we get Column B,C,D,...K.

The second formula is the same as your's but the impoted range is `osm!A:K` put in a `Lambda` call with the name `i` "you can name it any thing you like, i is short for import" so you dont need to write the range refrence every time.

Used formulas help
[**`ARRAYFORMULA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) - [**`LAMBDA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) - [**`QUERY`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) - [**`LOWER`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094083) - [**`AND`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093301)

Comment: The result of `arrayformula(A2:B & C2:D)` is two columns, not one.

Comment: The range reference text strings quoted in the question _are_ of the same height.

Comment: @doubleunary the reference but not the actual sheet, you can't know!, if they are diffrent we get mismatched row error. if not one of the ranges is modified in the formula

Comment: All the range reference text strings quoted in the question point to the same sheet and the same start row, therefore those ranges are of the same height. The problem is most likely with one of the `importrange()` calls failing.

Comment: @doubleunary my bad i did'nt pay attention to the id is  `Links!C2` not `Links`.

Comment: @Anderson the answer is updated take a look!

Comment: A very complex solution! A thing to study, I really appreciate your help!! 

Comment: Hope you can do an explanation, I'm just a newbie, a couple of hours using Gsheets ! thank you again! (or if there is material out there  I could check to improve)

Comment: @Anderson The explanation is added, this may seem complicated for someone new but it's your formula(more complex) tweaked a bit, you can learn by solving problems, youtube, written guides and courses(every beginner course with good reviews).